# Coordinator layout does not display in order

Tags: android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, nestedscrollview

I have a `TextView` inside a `NestedScrollView`

My XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/header"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:background="#AAA"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
            android:text="@string/lorem"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:textColor="#FFF"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

But the `TextView` is not displayed before scrolling
It's just a black screen below the image
[image: TextView not displayed before scrolling]

And TextView is dragged along while scrolling

[image: TextView is dragged along while scrolling]

Java code:

```
    public android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar;
    public CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar;

@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.event_details2);
            toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.anim_toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
            collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Event Name");
            ImageView header = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.header);
            collapsingToolbar.setContentScrimColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        }
```

How can I correct this? What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

Using TextView inside a LinearLayout which is inside the NestedScrollView solved this problem. But why is the LinearLayout required? Why am I not able to use TextView directly under NestedScrollView?